# Express reject when body type not as expected

Tags: node.js, typescript, express

I am writing a node server using express and I would like to enforce the types I am receiving in body. For example:

```
interface User {
  uid: string,
  email?: string,
  active: boolean,
}

app.put('/user', (req, res) => {
  const user: User = req.body;
}
```

I would like it for express to throw an error in the above example if the body differs from `User` type.

I haven't found any elegant solutions on how to solve this (as far as I can tell, there is no such way to do it with typescript). Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: You should use some validator such as https://json-schema.org/. Joi looks popular now too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [express-validator](https://express-validator.github.io/docs/) to do validation in your data.

It's a lib to use with commonjs.

There is an option to use [schema validation](https://express-validator.github.io/docs/schema-validation.html) too.